# Ansible playbook jinja2 logic fails when server is "unreachable"

Tags: ansible, jinja2

This playbook works fine by sending the email with jinja2 logic  **only when all the hosts in inventory are reachable**. If any one of the **server is "unreachable" the "send mail" play fails** with below error

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'up_time'

**How can the unreachable error be skipped in the mail play. Please help**

```
    tasks:

        - name: "check host status"
          ping:
          register: ping_result
        - name: "group by host_status"
          group_by:
             key: "host_status_{{ ping_result.ping | default('success') }}"

   - name: check uptime
     hosts: all
     gather_facts: no
     ignore_unreachable: yes
     ignore_errors: yes
     become: no

     tasks:
       - name: check uptime
         raw: uptime |awk '{print $3}'
         register: up_time

   - name: send mail
     hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: no
     ignore_unreachable: yes
     ignore_errors: yes
     become: no
     tasks:
       - name: Communication on high uptime servers
         mail:
           host: relay.cust.services
           port: 25
           from: abc@xyz.com
           to: abc@xyz.com
           subject: Communication on high uptime servers
           body: |-
             {% for server, servervars in hostvars.items() %}
             {% if servervars.up_time.stdout |int >= 10 %}
                {{"Consider rebooting the server ** "}} {{server}} {{" ** for better performance as it has high uptime of days : "}}{{ servervars.up_time.stdout }}
             {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining another play, you can add a conditional task to your first play and delegate it to `localhost`. Example:

```
- name: check uptime
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
  become: no

  tasks:
    - name: check uptime
      raw: uptime |awk '{print $3}'
      register: up_time
    - name: Communication on high uptime servers
      mail:
        host: relay.cust.services
        port: 25
        ...
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: up_time is not failed
```

If you want to stick to two plays, you have to set `up_time` as a fact to make it available in other plays.

Comment: Added them in the same play and dlegated to localhost and when condition. it failed trying to send mail from all servers
- name: check uptime
- name: Communication on high uptime servers
  mail:
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: up_time is not failed
Output
TASK [check uptime] 
changed: [cyxynalwpf]
changed: [ceaxnalwif]
TASK [Communication on high uptime servers] 
fatal: [cyxynalwpf]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
fatal: [ceaxnalwif]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was:

Comment: could you help me with set_fact as i would like to define in different plays.

Answer (score 0):

Able to figure out the issue and fixed it with "if" condition in mail play.

```
{% for server, servervars in hostvars.items()  %}
**{% if servervars.up_time.stdout is defined -%}**
  {% if servervars.up_time.stdout |int >= 2 %}
   {{"Consider rebooting the server ** "}} {{server}} {{" ** for better performance as it has high uptime of days : "}}{{ servervars.up_time.stdout }}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```